# Norm of linear functional on $c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

> Consider the space $c_0$ with its usual norm. For every element
> $u = (u_1, u_2, \ldots) \in c_0$ define
> $$f(u) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}{u_n}\,.$$
> I would like to prove that $f$ is continuous and find its norm.

Well, clearly $f$ is linear, then I'm trying this:
\begin{align}
|f(u)|
&\leq \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}{u_n}\right| \\
&\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|{u_n}|\\
&\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}\|u\|
\end{align}
Finally
$$|f(u)|\leq\|u\|\;\Longrightarrow\,\|f\|\leq 1$$
I believe $\|f\|=1$, but I've been looking for a sequence $u$ such that
$$\|f\|\geq\frac{|f(u)|}{\|u\|}$$

Comment: There's no single sequence that achieves the supremum. Instead take $u=(1,1,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: I took $u_k = (1, 1, 1, 1....,1,0,0,0...0)$ when 1 appears k times, finally:
$$||f|| \geq \frac{|f(u)|}{|u|}\rightarrow ||f|| \geq 1 - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} $$
then ||f|| \geq 1, is correct?

Comment: @Chrystomath your comment should be made into an answer in my opinion